# How do I take text info from a text field from Unity and assign it to a variable in C#?

Tags: c#, user-interface, variables, text, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a register/login system in Unity using C# and MySql.

Here is the line of code not working

```
username = GameObject.Find("/Canvas/TextFields/InputUsername/Text".ToString());
```

Whether I add the .ToString or not isn't working. How do I get the text info from the text field?

I am looking at the Unity info and a lot of the examples say something like GameObject.Find(Hand). How can it find what it is talking about?

I am getting the error Cannot implicitly convert.

I have tried a lot of other things too but none of them seem to work.

Edit: One of the things I have tried is using the .GetComponent but that doesn't work either.

Also, for some reason I could not post this yesterday in class because it said I posted something within the previous 90 minutes but did not, does anyone know how to FIX this problem?

Comment: How is your textfield set up? Is it from a script attached to a GameObject? GameObject.find() gives you a reference to a game object within the scene. You'll want something like

`user name = GameObject.Find("NAME").GetComponent("SCRIPTNAME").textfieldVariable;`

Comment: @Andy It's from the Unity program itself from a scene, it's not made from a script. Here is a picture. http://i.imgur.com/bPAWdmg.png

What would I use to call it? The "Name" thing doesn't seem to work in this instance.

Comment: @Andy Tried

    username = GameObject.Find ("/Canvas/TextFields/InputUsername").GetComponent ("Input Field").Text;

and the only error is that Text does not contain an extension method or definition.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
username = GameObject.Find("/Canvas/TextFields/InputUsername/Text").GetComponent<Text>().text;
```

Comment: Instead of using GetComponent<Text>().Text;
Use GetComponent<Text>().text;

As Capital T in Text is the Class and text is the instance field.

Comment: I am getting an error that says the type or namespace 'text' could not be found, it says that I might be missing a using directive or assembly reference.

I am using

http://i.imgur.com/8BmuHNy.png

My references are http://i.imgur.com/IQ9ncay.png

Sorry, I tried double spacing and double entering and can't seem to get the lines to skip to the next/format properly, so I used images.

Comment: Try adding `using UnityEngine.UI;`